# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined ' getting this error in the console when i use req.query.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

'Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined' getting this error in the console
when i use req.query.id

here is my index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
    const path = require("path");
    const port = 8000;
    const request = require('request');

    const db = require('./config/mongoose');
    const Contact = require('./models/contact');

    const app = express(); 
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(express.static('assets')) 
    var contactList = [
    {
        name: 'Vijay chakradhari',
        phone: '9222949595'
    },
    {
        name: 'Vijay yaduvanshi',
        phone: '9223949596'
    },
    {
        name: 'Krishna chakradhari',
        phone: '9224949595'
    }
    ]

    app.get('/', async function(req, res){
    try {
        const contacts = await Contact.find({});
        return res.render('home',{
            title: "Contact List",
            contact_list: contacts
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error in fetching contacts from db");
        return;
    }
    }); 

    app.get('/practice', function(req, res){
    return res.render('practice', 
    {'title': 'It is only Practice'})
    })


    app.post('/create-contact', async function(req, res){
    try {
        const newContact = await Contact.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            phone: req.body.phone
        });
        console.log(newContact);
        return res.redirect('back');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in creating a contact!');
    }
    });

    app.get('/delete-contact', async function(req, res){
    
    let id = req.query.id;
    console.log('The contact id is:', req.query.id);
 
    try {
       await Contact.findByIdAndDelete(id);
       res.redirect('back');
    } catch (err) {
       console.log('Error in deleting a contact in Database');
       return;
    }
    });
    

    app.listen(port, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error in running the server', err)
    }
    console.log('App is listening on port ' + port)   
    });
```

home.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= title%></title>
     <!--FONTAWESOME KIT-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9f41a01f34.js" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- <h1>Rendered with EJS</h1> -->

    <h1 id="page-heading">
        <i class="fa-duotone fa-address-card fa-xl" style="--fa-secondary- 
    opacity: 0.5;"></i>
        My Contact List</h1>
    <div id="contact-list-container">
        <ul>
            <%
            for (let i of contact_list){%>
                    <li class="contact">
                        <div class="details">
                            <p><%= i.name%> 
                               <%= i.phone%>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="delete-button">
                            <a href="/delete-contact/?id<%= i._id%>">
                                <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            <%}%>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form id="new-contact-form" action="/create-contact" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter your name" 
    required>
        <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="enter your phone" 
    required>
        <button type="submit">Add Contact</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/JS/home.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

mongoose.js file

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/contacts_list_db');
    
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'error connecting to 
    database'));
    
    
    db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Successfully connected to the DataBase');
    });
```

```
Database collection
```

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    })

    const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);

    module.exports = Contact;
```

i was expecting to get contact id when i use 'Delete Contact button' but instead i get this error 'undefined(request)'

'Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined ' getting this error in the console when i use req.query.id

Answer (score -1):

You can `console.log(req.query)` before putting the `console.log(req.query.id)` to check if you're getting the id from the request.
If you are not getting the id from the `req.query` try with this below

```
<div class="delete-button">
    <a href="/delete-contact?id<%=i._id%>">
      <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this html different from whats in the question?

Comment: From `<a href="/delete-contact/?id<%=  i._id%>">` to `<a href="/delete-contact?id<%=i._id%>">`. You can try removing the space after the `=` sign.

Comment: @Haris Great!!! i got it by loging req.query but why it does not work with req.query.id  Also the problem is i can not delete contact even after pressing the delete button also there is no error message. can you please go through the Delete button code part again ? thanks in advance